# Trying out Range and Close in go Channel

Tags: go, range, channel

I am trying to use range and close in the channel to understand it better.
Below is a code sample I tried based on my understanding.

After executing the below code, I get the error mentioned below the code.

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    str := "hello"
    hiChannel := make(chan string, 5)
    for j := 1; j <= 5; j++ {
        go func(hi string) {
            hiChannel <- hi
        }(str)
    }
    defer close(hiChannel)
    for s := range hiChannel {
        fmt.Println(s)
    }
}
```

Error:

```
go run restsample/restsample.go
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
main.main()
        C:/Users/Indian/personal/Workspaces/Learning/src/restsample/restsample.go:16 +0x169
exit status 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for s := range hiChannel
```

The for statement exit when you close the `hiChannel`, actually you are not closing the channel, therefore, your code raise a deadlock.
There are several ways to close a channel, for example, you can count how many string you have print and then you can close the channel.
Or you can create a signal channel and close when you have received all the necessary information.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Tinwor feedback, I tried added few lines to check the message count and it worked. Thanks.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    str := "hello"
    hiChannel := make(chan string, 5)
    for j := 1; j <= 5; j++ {
        go func(hi string) {
            hiChannel <- hi
        }(str)
    }
    i := 1
    for s := range hiChannel {
        i++
        if i == 5 {
            fmt.Println(s)
            close(hiChannel)
        } else {
            fmt.Println(s)
        }
    }
}
```